# Why has my Avatar in Pokémon GO disappeared? My accounts are intact

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokemon GO Avatar has disappeared. All my accounts and Pokemon are intact but where my character should be walking around the there's just a little shadow..  what's going on??

Answer (score 1):

Trying closing the Pokemon Go app and reopening it. There are still bugs in the game, and I find that relaunching it fixes most of them.